# Do all Stack Exchange sites upvote a user's first question and/or answer?

Tags: discussion, questions, answers, new-users, up-votes

I recently discovered that there are hundreds of Stack Exchange sites, and I joined the ones that I think I need. After posting my first question and/or answer in all sites, I realised that my post is always upvoted once it is given. Even if I get some downvotes after that upvote. So is that the website's work or it is community members?

Comment: It's community. There is no automatic upvoting. There is *sort of* automatic downvoting but it goes hand in hand with spam flags.

Comment: An automatic upvote for every new post would have oppurtunities for abuse:  You could post tons of posts, and win 10 extra rep for each one, for instance, winning new privileges before you were ready for them.  So yes, it's definitely the work of the community.

Comment: i meant automatic upvoting for the user's first post

Comment: @Muhammadrasul, it would still have opportunities for abuse.

Comment: @Olie How? I can post first time only once, that's why it's called the FIRST post.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

No, this is not automatic. Your first post on each Stack Exchange site *is* reviewed by other users in the [First Posts review queue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/146988/295232) and users are encouraged to vote (up or down) those posts. On average, first posts by new users are lower quality, so if you write a decent post, chances are that reviewers are positively surprised and upvote your post, even though it might not be useful for themselves.